# JSP - javabean returns null, but why?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

When an user presses the login button on a JSP, the request is submitted to my servlet which gets the entered username and password from the login form by `getParameter()`.

The username and password are stored in a javabean. If I put a `println()` statement which shows the values of `bean.getUsername()` and `bean.getPassword()`, then it prints the username and password in the log.

But the following code snippet on my master page

```
<jsp:useBean id="bean" class="package.Bean" scope="session" />
<jsp:getProperty name="bean" property="username" />
```

shows `null` instead of the username. What am I doing wrong?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    // Store username and password in bean from login.jsp
    Bean bean = new bean();
    bean.setUsername(username);
    bean.setPassword(password);

    // check login details with database

       if (login success)
    {   
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("username", username);

        // redirect user to welcome page
    }
    else
        // login failed
}
```

Comment: Show the for your servlet. Are you adding the bean to session scope in your servlet?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you haven't let the servlet store the bean in the session scope. But since you're using servlets anyway, forget the `<jsp:useBean>` thing. It's technically worthless. It also tight-couples the model with the view.

Just let the servlet put the bean in session scope:

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user); // Store logged-in user in session.
    response.sendRedirect("home"); // Redirect to login home page or whatever.
} else {
    request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown login, please try again"); // Store error message for redisplay in login page.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response); // Forward to login page.
}
```

Then in the user home page, just use EL (Expression Language) to access the `User` bean.

```
<p>Welcome, <c:out value="${user.username}" /></p>
```

The `${foo}` basically searches for an attribute which is stored with the name `foo` in page, request, session and application scopes and returns the first non-null value. In this case, the `${user}` will refer to your `User` bean which you've stored in the session scope. The `${user.username}` will basically display the return value of `user.getUsername()`.

The `<c:out>`  is by the way not necessary, but it prevents your page from potential XSS attacks.

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, `package` is a keyword and thus an illegal package name. Please take care when posting oversimplified code examples ;) Rather use `com.example` or something if you'd like to obfuscate package names.

---

**Update**: as per your update, you're setting the username in the session scope, not the bean itself. Even though you would be able to display it by `${username}`, in order to be able to use `${bean.username}`, you need to fix it accordingly as described in above answer.

Comment: Really? I created the bean object to store username and password. Confused.

Comment: I have set the username in the session scope, not really seeing how my code differs from yours tbh.

Comment: You're attempting to access a bean using `<jsp:useBean>` which you haven't put in the session scope at all, so JSP is creating a brand new one instead of reusing an existing one in session. But after all you don't need to create a new one, so just get rid of those two lines in JSP and just use `${username}` to display the username. Read the answer once again (not only the code, but also the text) to find the subtle differences and also the links to learn more about how it all ought to work.