# CastException:Java.lang.String can not cast to class

Tags: jsp, servlets, javabeans

I have a query..

1. Servlet has called some business logic(at class "MyPack.abc") and got some return   value.
2. Now this value is set to session "result" and sendRedirect("xy.jsp") is called.
3. I want to fetch this value at jsp with the help of `<jsp:useBean id="result"     class="MyPack.abc" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>` But `<jsp:useBean>` is showing an exception CastException (Java.lang.String can not cast to class).

Here is code:

`index.jsp`

```
<html> 
<body> 
  <form action="MyController"> 
   <input type="text" name="name"><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="submit">
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

servlet `MyController`

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import myPack.*;
 public class MyController extends HttpServlet 
 { 
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
   { 
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 
      abc d=new abc(); 
      d.setName((String)request.getParameter("name"));
      String s=(String) d.getName(); 

      HttpSession session=request.getSession(); 
      session.setAttribute("result",s); 
      response.sendRedirect("xy.jsp"); 
    }
  }
```

bean class `abc` in myPack

```
 package myPack; 

 public class abc { 

 public abc() { } 
 public String name; 

 public String getName() { 
   return name; 
 } 
 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name; 
 } 
}
```

`xy.jsp`

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="myPack.abc" %> 
 <html>
 <body>
  <jsp:useBean id="result" class="myPack.abc" scope="session"></jsp:useBean> 
  <jsp:getProperty property="name" name="r"></jsp:getProperty>
 </body> 
 </html>
```

But it is throwing a CastException (Java.lang.String can not cast to class).

Comment: Can you attach your error log. And also the code where it is throwing the error.?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete posting..    1. Servlet has called some business logic(at class "MyPack.abc") and got some return value. 
    2. Now this value is set to session "result" and sendRedirect("xy.jsp") is called. 
    3. I   want to fetch this value at jsp with the help of <jsp:useBean id="result"   class="myPack.abc" scope="session"> </jsp:useBean>
    But <jsp:useBean> is showing a exception CastException (Java.lang.String can not cast to  class).

Comment: You haven't reported the error message accurately. Try again. Paraphrases or what you thought it said aren't good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I solved your problem by making lot of efforts. As your information is not easy to read from comments.

```
<jsp:useBean id="beanInstanceName" scope="page|request|session|application"
             class="package.class" type="package.class" 
             beanName="package.class | <%= expression %>">
</jsp:useBean>
```

Your **mistake** is

```
session.setAttribute("result",s); //setting the attribute with String key as result
```

and the line on `xy.jsp` throw exception `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to myPack.abc`

```
<jsp:useBean id="result" class="myPack.abc" scope="session"></jsp:useBean>
```

Look at the first attribute of syntax `id="beanInstanceName"` it is the instance of your bean class `abc` and you have used `result` which is **key of session attribute** it means that your are trying to set object of type class `abc` to `String` result.

**Solution:**
Just rename id attribute of your `xy.jsp` `result` to something like r or abc. This solves your exception problem, but after running app you will see name is `null`. This is because **you're attempting to access a `bean` using  which you haven't put in the session scope at all, so JSP is creating a brand new one instead of reusing an existing one in session. You are setting only String name attribute in session.**
For getting the bean property `name` on jsp you have to edit your `xy.jsp`

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="myPack.abc" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>
   <c:out value="${result}" />
</body> 
</html>
```

Before running your app add [jstl-1.2.jar](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) in `WEB-INF\lib` folder. This works fine.

Some useful links:

1. [jsp wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
2. [jsp useBean](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-useBean-action)
3. [why jstl ${result}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058322/jsp-javabean-returns-null-but-why)